# Use wildcard with Mutate Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I was just wondering if it was possible to just wild card in select for Dplyr

```
  H3_m <- fd %>% 
    select(c(M_DV*)) %>%
    na.omit

  fd <- fd %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(DV = mean(c(M_DV*), na.rm = TRUE),
    )
```

Comment: See `?select_helpers`

Comment: Simple example: `iris %>% select_at(vars(contains("Sepal")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `matches`

```
fd %>%
   select(matches("M_DV*"))
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use this inside the mean function?

Comment: @Lowpar  If you meant to to `summarise` then `summarise_at(vars(matches("M_DV*)), mean)`

Comment: Thanks for the info, in this instance I would be using rowwise means, so a summary would not necessarily help. I can always just write it manually :D

Comment: @Lowpar In that case `fd %>% mutate(Mean = rowMeans(.[grep("M_DV*", names(.))]))` or so